# Is this considered as using private functions in iPhone dev, and thus illegal?

Tags: ios, scroll, uiwebview, iphone-privateapi

I'm trying to disable scrolling for a `UIWebView` and the only way I found is using this way:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

id scroller = [[Webview subviews] lastObject];
int count;
Method *method = class_copyMethodList([scroller class], &count);
int i;
for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
    if (strcmp(method_getName(method[i]), "setScrollingEnabled:") == 0)
        break;
}
IMP test = method_getImplementation(method[i]);
test(scroller, @selector(setScrollingEnabled:), NO);
```

Is this considered to be an illegal way of using the iPhone SDK? Can this cause my application to be rejected for the App store?

Answer (score 4):

wouldn't it be a lot simpler to do this:

`if ([scroller respondsToSelector: @selector(setScrollingEnabled:)]) [scroller setScrollingEnabled: NO]`

This avoids any of the potential method calls they might scan your binary for (not sure how they verify 'legality'). It's still not 100% kosher, but definitely safer.

Comment: I did it this way, and my app was still rejected.

Comment: Are you sure it was for this? In iOS 5, the scrollView is accessible via a property on the web view, so this shouldn't be much of an issue anymore.

Comment: Certain - they mentioned setScrollingEnabled by name. Useful to know that about 5.0, thanks. I'm building for 4.0 and above at the moment.

Comment: No. This can't work either. The function should not be called (applies up to iOS 6). Use this `scrollView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;` instead

Answer (score 2):

I just got my app rejected because of using setScrollingEnabled, so BEWARE!

Their message: "The non-public API that is included in your application is setScrollingEnabled"

Answer (score 2):

If the method isn't in the .h file, it's private. It's a pretty simple rule. The fact you need to perform any runtime "shenanigans" for a simple message send should be telling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is considered illegal. I actually received a 'warning' saying that setSCrollingEnabled was part of a private framework. They approved the app but said that I needed to remove this call for the next update I submit.

Answer (score 1):

This works –

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[myWebView subviews] lastObject];
scrollView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;
```

This fixes the problem, while also keeping the links click-able, any scrollViews it’s embedded in scrollable, and uses only public API’s.

I found that the javascript solutions prevented the WebViews from working correctly if it was embedded in a `UIScrollView` and setting `userInteractionEnabled` to false prevented links in the webView from being click-able.

Answer (score 0):

It might be questionable, but not a cause for rejection as long as you have a fallback behavior when/if the method can not be found. There are worse abuses that have passed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe they think you did it another way, like take the contents of an offscreen UIWebView and displayed it in a plain UIIMage view, or take the HTML content of a page restrict its size and render it in a UIWebView.

Comment: I'd like to know how to "take the contents of an offscreen UIWebView and displayed it in a plain UIIMage view". Any tips?

Comment: You can use -renderInContext.  If you need more details, start a new questions since it is hard to post code in comments.